# Prove $P(A∩B)≤1/2[P(A)+P(B)]$

Tags: probability

I'm having some trouble with this proof. I know that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$. If I take 1/2 of the whole right hand side I can say $P(A\cap B) \le P(A)/2+P(B)/2-P(A\cup B)/2$, thus $P(A\cap B)\le[P(A)+P(B)]/2-P(A\cup B)$, and the first half is what I need, but I don't know how what to do with the $-P(A\cup B)/2$.

Answer (score 5):

By the axioms of probability theory, you have
$$P(A \cap B) \le P(A)$$
(since $(A \cap B) \subset A)$ and similarly
$$P(A \cap B) \le P(B)$$
Adding these equations and dividing by 2 should give the desired result..

Comment: Using that, if P(A∩B)≤P(A) and P(A∩B)≤P(B), then certainly P(A∩B)≤P(A)+P(B) and I'm in the right direction. Now, how do I know that that P(A∩B) is also less than or equal to half of P(A)+P(B)?

Comment: @erl92: You must read my post carefully: You have to sum up the inequalities. Then you obtain $2P(A \cap B) \le P(A)+P(B)$ which is very close to the result you need to prove..

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. It all makes sense now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> I know that $P(A∩B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(A∪B)$ .
>
> If I take 1/2 of the whole right hand side I can say $P(A∩B)≤P(A)/2+P(B)/2−P(A∪B)/2$

No.  Let's put some number on that.

You're saying that if $0.2 = 0.4 + 0.4 - 0.6$ then $0.2\leq 0.2 + 0.2 - 0.3 = 0.1$